# Retrieve latest posts from a Facebook group via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm a moderator of a Facebook group and I'd like to write some code to retrieve the latests posts (may 10, or more) from this group.

This is the code I wrote

```
require_once 'src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fbApp = new Facebook\FacebookApp('{my-app-id}', '{my-app-secret}');
$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($fbApp, {AuthToken},'GET','{group-id}?limit=10');


// Send the request to Graph
try {
  $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
// When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
var_dump($graphNode);
```

**Response:**
Graph returned an error: Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request

Where's the bug? 
I googled so many sites whitout finding any real solution.

Comment: What sense is `{group-id}?limit=10` supposed to make as a request path? Posts are retrieved via the `feed` edge.